# error between clEnqueueMapImage and clEnqueueUnmapMemObject

Tags: opencl

Why I can't memcpy for mapped buffer:

```
void* map_ptr = clEnqueueMapImage(d->GetQueue(), DeviceMem, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, HostOrigin, Region, &HostRowPitch, &HostSlicePitch, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    memcpy(map_ptr, Data, HostWidth * HostHeight * sizeof(unsigned int));           ///ERROR ????????????

    *Error = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(d->GetQueue(), DeviceMem, map_ptr, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

CreateBuffer is:

```
cl_mem temp = clCreateBuffer(d->GetContext(), CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, Size, NULL, Error);
```

HostSlicePitch != 0

```
size_t HostOrigin[3] = {0,0,0};
size_t Region[3] = {sizeof(unsigned int)*HostWidth, HostHeight, HostDepth};
```

Comment: I try speed up transfer for this lib: https://github.com/amcelroy/OpenCLV

Comment: What kind of error do you get? 
Also, there won't be much performance benefit of map + memcpy vs simply clEnqueueWrite or Read functions, since your memcpy to another memory location will cancel any benefit from Map/Unmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Need clFlush between Map and UnMap.
https://github.com/CyberRSR/OpenCLV

```
void* map_ptr = clEnqueueMapBuffer(d->GetQueue(), DeviceMem, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, HostWidth*HostHeight*HostDepth, NULL, NULL, d->GetEvent(), Error);

    clFlush(d->GetQueue());
    d->ThrowMemEvent(DeviceMem);

    memcpy(map_ptr, Data, HostWidth*HostHeight*HostDepth*sizeof(unsigned int));         

    *Error = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(d->GetQueue(), DeviceMem, map_ptr, 0, NULL, d->GetEvent());
```